# Dictionary inside for loop not working as expected TypeError: replace() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace words which are abbreviations with full words. For e.g. replace `cause` with `because`. However i get an error. Here contraction is my dictionary and I am trying to create a function that will take words from contraction dictionary and replace the keys with the values. For e.g. cause is a key, because is the value etc.

Dictionary

```
contraction = {'cause':'because',
              'aint': 'am not',
              'aren\'t': 'are not'}
```

Defining Function to replace words like cause, arent with full words - because and are not etc.

```
def mapping_replacer(x,dic):
    for words in dic.keys():
        if ' ' + words + ' ' in x:
            x=x.replace(' '+ words +' ' ' '+dic[words]+' ' )
    return x
```

Calling the function. train is a database with a column content. I want to find words like cause, aren't from content column of train and replace them with because, are not etc.

```
train['content']=train['content'].apply(lambda x: mapping_replacer(x, contraction))
```

Error

```
  <ipython-input-122-4f7429b148ac> in mapping_replacer(x, dic)
      6     for words in dic.keys():
      7         if ' ' + words + ' ' in x:
----> 8             x=x.replace(' '+ words +' ' ' '+dic[words]+' ' )
      9     return x
     10 

TypeError: replace() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: `x=x.replace(' '+ words +' ', ' '+dic[words]+' ' )` note missing comma

Comment: `replace(string_you_want_to_replace, what_to_replace_it_with)` it looks like you forgot a comma in the function call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a second parameter to replace.

```
x = x.replace(' '+ words +' ' ' '+dic[words]+' ' )
```

I'm guessing you're supposed to put this.

```
x = x.replace(' ' + words + ' ', ' ' + dic[words] + ' ')
```